# Linq join query with left outer join throwing object reference not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I have a list and two tables. (This is a very simplified version of the actual schema, but should work for the question)

**List_A**
FPI
1
2
3
4

**Table_B**
FPI_______NI
2_________1
4_________2

**Table_C**
NI_______Name
1_________x
2_________y

My linq query:

```
(from a in List_A
 join b in Table_B on a.FPI equals b.FPI into ab
 from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join c in Table_C on b.FI equals c.FI into bc
 from c in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new {
   FPI = a.FPI,
   Name = c?.Name}).ToList();
```

this code throws an exception that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.
After a lot of trial and experiment, I have reached to a conclusion that in the second join when i'm doing `b.FI equals c.FI`, at that time it is failing for the entries for which there is no value in the Table_B.

The expected output of the query should be
**ABC**
FPI____NI___Name
1_____null__null
2_____1_____x   
3_____null__null
4_____2_____y

I'm not sure why this error is coming and what would be the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i have done that too. And i have even tried removing the arguments which might throw exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would be perfectly valid if it was a LINQ to Entities query translated to SQL.

However, since the root of the query is `List_A` which is not a `IQueryable`, the whole query executes in LINQ to Objects context, where you are supposed to perform `null` checks on right side variable of the left outer join anywhere, including further join conditions.

So the simple fix would be using

```
join c in Table_C on b?.FI equals c.FI into bc
```

However, note that the query is highly inefficient. Since it is resolved to `Enumerable` methods, the whole `Table_B` and `Table_C` will be read in memory and then joined.

A better approach would be to separate the db and in memory queries:

```
var dbQuery =
    from b in Table_B
    join c in Table_C on b.FI equals c.FI into bc
    from c in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { b.FPI, c.Name };

var query =
    from a in List_A
    join bc in dbQuery on a.FPI equals bc.FPI into abc
    from bc in abc.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
       FPI = a.FPI,
       Name = bc?.Name
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 var list=(from a in Table_A
                join b in Table_B on a.FPI equals b.FPI into ab
                from b in ab.ToList()
                join c in Table_C on b.NI equals c.NI into bc
                from c in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new {
                FPI = a.FPI,
                Name = c.Name}).ToList();
```

**Update**

```
         var list = (from a in Table_A
                     join b in Table_B on a.FPI equals b.FPI into ab
                     from b in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     join c in Table_C on b == null ? 0 : b.NI equals c.NI into bc
                     from c in bc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         FBI = a.FPI,
                         NI = c != null ? c.NI : null,//if NI is nullable
                         //NI = c != null ? c.NI : 0,//if NI is not nullable
                         Name = c!=null?c.Name:null

                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works without an exception but returns the rows which have values for the column FPI in the the Table_B. Purpose of this query is to get a left join.